# Maven struts2 modular archetype failing to generate !

Tags: maven-2, struts2, maven-archetype

I am trying to generate struts 2 modular archetype using maven but always getting error as archetype not present here is a full output :

```
C:\Users\Administrator>mvn archetype:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'archetype'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [archetype:generate] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing archetype:generate
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus
.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
[INFO] [archetype:generate {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.
archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: internal -> appfuse-basic-jsf (AppFuse archetype for creating a web applicati
on with Hibernate, Spring and JSF)
2: internal -> appfuse-basic-spring (AppFuse archetype for creating a web applic
ation with Hibernate, Spring and Spring MVC)
3: internal -> appfuse-basic-struts (AppFuse archetype for creating a web applic
ation with Hibernate, Spring and Struts 2)
4: internal -> appfuse-basic-tapestry (AppFuse archetype for creating a web appl
ication with Hibernate, Spring and Tapestry 4)
5: internal -> appfuse-core (AppFuse archetype for creating a jar application wi
th Hibernate and Spring and XFire)
6: internal -> appfuse-modular-jsf (AppFuse archetype for creating a modular app
lication with Hibernate, Spring and JSF)
7: internal -> appfuse-modular-spring (AppFuse archetype for creating a modular
application with Hibernate, Spring and Spring MVC)
8: internal -> appfuse-modular-struts (AppFuse archetype for creating a modular
application with Hibernate, Spring and Struts 2)
9: internal -> appfuse-modular-tapestry (AppFuse archetype for creating a modula
r application with Hibernate, Spring and Tapestry 4)
10: internal -> maven-archetype-j2ee-simple (A simple J2EE Java application)
11: internal -> maven-archetype-marmalade-mojo (A Maven plugin development proje
ct using marmalade)
12: internal -> maven-archetype-mojo (A Maven Java plugin development project)
13: internal -> maven-archetype-portlet (A simple portlet application)
14: internal -> maven-archetype-profiles ()
15: internal -> maven-archetype-quickstart ()
16: internal -> maven-archetype-site-simple (A simple site generation project)
17: internal -> maven-archetype-site (A more complex site project)
18: internal -> maven-archetype-webapp (A simple Java web application)
19: internal -> jini-service-archetype (Archetype for Jini service project creat
ion)
20: internal -> softeu-archetype-seam (JSF+Facelets+Seam Archetype)
21: internal -> softeu-archetype-seam-simple (JSF+Facelets+Seam (no persistence)
 Archetype)
22: internal -> softeu-archetype-jsf (JSF+Facelets Archetype)
23: internal -> jpa-maven-archetype (JPA application)
24: internal -> spring-osgi-bundle-archetype (Spring-OSGi archetype)
25: internal -> confluence-plugin-archetype (Atlassian Confluence plugin archety
pe)
26: internal -> jira-plugin-archetype (Atlassian JIRA plugin archetype)
27: internal -> maven-archetype-har (Hibernate Archive)
28: internal -> maven-archetype-sar (JBoss Service Archive)
29: internal -> wicket-archetype-quickstart (A simple Apache Wicket project)
30: internal -> scala-archetype-simple (A simple scala project)
31: internal -> lift-archetype-blank (A blank/empty liftweb project)
32: internal -> lift-archetype-basic (The basic (liftweb) project)
33: internal -> cocoon-22-archetype-block-plain ([http://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/m
aven-plugins/])
34: internal -> cocoon-22-archetype-block ([http://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/maven-p
lugins/])
35: internal -> cocoon-22-archetype-webapp ([http://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/maven-
plugins/])
36: internal -> myfaces-archetype-helloworld (A simple archetype using MyFaces)
37: internal -> myfaces-archetype-helloworld-facelets (A simple archetype using
MyFaces and facelets)
38: internal -> myfaces-archetype-trinidad (A simple archetype using Myfaces and
 Trinidad)
39: internal -> myfaces-archetype-jsfcomponents (A simple archetype for create c
ustom JSF components using MyFaces)
40: internal -> gmaven-archetype-basic (Groovy basic archetype)
41: internal -> gmaven-archetype-mojo (Groovy mojo archetype)
Choose a number:  (1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17/18/19/20/21/22/23/2
4/25/26/27/28/29/30/31/32/33/34/35/36/37/38/39/40/41) 15: : 8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The defined artifact is not an archetype
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 27 08:22:38 IST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/21M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\Administrator>
```

What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maven *central* repository is very likely missing some artifacts. Use this instead:

```
mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse \
                     -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-modular-struts \
                     -DremoteRepositories=http://static.appfuse.org/repository \
                     -DarchetypeVersion=2.0-m5 \
                     -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
                     -DartifactId=myproject
```